# History in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm running Ubuntu 9.1 and every time I open a terminal window, I lose the previous command's history. How can I configure it so it's kept even after rebooting?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/37576/can-history-files-be-unified-in-bash

Comment: I get 
bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 0: `; history -a; history -n'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the permissions on ~/.bash_history? Can your user modify it?

Alternatively, are you exiting out of the previous window first?

Comment: Bingo!, for some reason it was owned by root. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using Bash.

Try this command at Bash prompt:

```
shopt -p histappend
```

If it says:

```
shopt -u histappend
```

then add this line in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s histappend
```

Comment: The output of "shopt -p histappend" is "shopt -s histappend"

Comment: Make sure you exit from Bash cleanly (e.g. with the `exit` command). Bash only updates `.bash_history` on a clean exit, so if the process dies unexpectedly (e.g. reboot, closing an xterm), it may not have a chance to update the file.